# blip.tv ftp structure

Tags: php, perl, apache-2.2, ftp

My website need a FTP structure like blip.tv has.
Each user has a FTP login

Example:
Host: ftp.domain.com
Username: johndoe
password: 123123

Users will able to upload files by FTP, but files will be save in many different servers.
file name and location will be store in mysql database.
I don't know where to start.

Can anyone tell me what need to be done?

Thanks

Comment: More suitable on serverfault.com I think, as it's more about infrastructure design than programming. At any rate, you need to provide more info about what server(s) and platforms are available to you. There are many ways to do this

Comment: Why was this closed and not migrated? Voting to reopen so it can be migrated to SF.

Comment: And now it's here it's an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either configure existing ftp daemon or write your own ftp server using modules from CPAN. See ftpd/Net::FTPServer and POE::Component::Server::FTP.